# Is babelrc ignored if tsconfig.json is present?

Tags: typescript, react-native, tsconfig

**EDIT: After playing around I discovered that changing the import from:**

`import * as API from 'app/lib/api'`

**to:**

`import * as API from 'app/lib/api/index.ts'`

**works. Why do you have to be explicit like this when importing a `.ts` file into a `.js` file? It works the other way around. Is it something off with babel?**

**An alias in my `.babelrc` like this doesn't make a difference:**

```
{
  "presets": ["module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"],
  "plugins": [
    ["module-resolver", {
      "root": ["."],
      "alias": {
        "app/lib/api": "app/lib/api/index.ts",
      }
    }]
  ]
}
```

**ORIGINAL POST:**

I have an existing project I am migrating over to typescript. This is my file structure:

```
my_app/
├─ app/
│  ├─ lib/
│  │  ├─ api/
│  │  │  ├─ index.ts
│  │  ├─ Iterable.js
├─ config/
│  ├─ config.js
├─ .babelrc
├─ tsconfig.json
```

All paths were working before I added typescript with this `.babelrc`:

```
{
  "presets": ["module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"],
  "plugins": [
    ["module-resolver", {
      "root": ["."]
    }]
  ]
}
```

In my `tsconfig.json`, I just set the `baseUrl` to my root. I didn't include any paths as I haven't needed them yet:

```
{
 "compilerOptions": {
   "baseUrl": "." 
  }
}
```

I only have one `.ts` file right now. In `index.ts` I am making this import:

`import CONFIG from 'config/config';`

This works fine. I was also able to run my app for awhile just fine. But suddenly I started getting this error:

```
Unable to resolve module app/lib/api from my_app/app/lib/Iterable.js: 
app/lib/api could not be found within the project or in these directories: 
node_modules 
../../../node_modules

If you are sure the module exists, try these steps:
1. Clear watchman watches: watchman watch-del-all
2. Delete node_modules and run yarn install
3. Reset Metro's cache: yarn start --reset-cache
4. Remove the cache: rm -rf /tmp/metro-*
```

The path in `Iterable.js` looks like this:

`import * as API from 'app/lib/api';`

I tried changing the path to this and the error goes away, so I know it is a path alias issue:

`import * as API from './app/lib/api'`

However, it just moves on down the line to the next `.js` file with the same issue(my codebase is larger than the file structure tree I provided).

I also tried changing `Iterable.js` to `Iterable.ts`, even though I'm not ready to do that yet and the error went away (but moves on to the next `.js` file as well). **So, it's like `.babelrc` isn't being applied or something.**

Additionally, I tried adding paths to `tsconfig.json` like this:

```
{
 "compilerOptions": {
   "baseUrl": ".",
   "paths": {
     "app/lib/api": ["app/lib/api"]
  },
}
```

That didn't work and since the location is the same as the alias I don't think this is necessary...

I read the React Native documentation on migrating over to typescript, read a ton of blogs on the subject, and looked through the typescript documentation and the `babel-plugin-module-resolver` documentation. I've tried all the suggestions on the error message, as well as restarting my computer, cleaning my xcode build folder, deleting derived data, and restarting vscode.

Does anything look off to a more trained eye? I thank you greatly in advance!

Comment: have you tried adding `paths` into `tsconfig`? https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping

Comment: @davidhu I did, to no avail, I will add that to the question. My understanding is you only need to add paths if the import location name is different from the absolute path. So, for example in the docs it says "jquery" represents "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery" and that is in relation to the baseUrl. If I followed that example "app/lib/api" would represent "app/lib/api" so I don't think it's necessary. I could be wrong though. Thank you for the help!

Comment: try changing paths to `"app": ["./app"]`

Comment: @davidhu No luck, thank you though. I thought `.js` files were ignored by `tsconfig.json`, is that not the case?

Comment: js files are not ignored unless you put them in the `exclude` key in tsconfig. Are you able to replicate this issue in a sample repo so I can reproduce it?

Comment: @davidhu That's very generous, I will try to do that. Did you see my edit to the post? I was able to get it to work if I made the import explicit, but still feel like there should be a cleaner way.

Comment: @davidhu I'm running into so many issues trying to create a sample project I think I will just be happy with the solution I found. Thanks for your time!